# React component and Apollo Client does not work "in real time"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, material-ui, react-apollo

I am trying to build a user system but I am getting confused with something since it does not work in real time.

I have created an example [Sandbox](https://jp581.csb.app/) to show my "issue" and my code. I didn't add any kind of validation stuff, it is just for example purposes.

Some of the issues (I see) are:

1. Button actions trigger on second click
2. Data won't refresh after created / deleted.

This is the `<UsersPage />` component:

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useMutation, useLazyQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { ADD_USER, LIST_USERS, DELETE_USER } from "../../../config/constants";
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";
import {
  Grid,
  Paper,
  TextField,
  Button,
  Typography,
  MenuItem,
  FormHelperText
} from "@material-ui/core";
import AddUserIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PersonAdd";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Table from "../../Table";

const styles = theme => ({
  grid: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3)
  },
  icon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  form: {
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    overflowX: "auto",
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit
  },
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    overflowX: "auto",
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  title: {
    margin: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 700
  },
  noRecords: {
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit
  }
});

const Users = props => {
  const [idState, setIdState] = useState(null);
  const [emailState, setEmailState] = useState("");
  const [passwordState, setPasswordState] = useState("");
  const [usersState, setUsersState] = useState([]);
  const [errorsState, setErrorsState] = useState({});
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState(false);
  const [addUser, addUserResponse] = useMutation(ADD_USER);
  const [loadUsers, usersResponse] = useLazyQuery(LIST_USERS);
  const [deleteUser, deleteUserResponse] = useMutation(DELETE_USER);
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  useEffect(() => {
    loadUsers();

    if (usersResponse.called && usersResponse.loading) {
      setLoadingState(true);
    } else if (usersResponse.called && !usersResponse.loading) {
      setLoadingState(false);
    }

    if (usersResponse.data) {
      setUsersState(usersResponse.data.getUsers);
    }
  }, [usersResponse.called, usersResponse.loading, usersResponse.data]);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (idState) {
    } else {
      addUser({
        variables: {
          email: emailState,
          password: passwordState
        }
      });
    }

    if (addUserResponse.called && addUserResponse.loading) {
      enqueueSnackbar("Creating user");
    }

    if (addUserResponse.error) {
      addUserResponse.error.graphQLErrors.map(exception => {
        const error = exception.extensions.exception;
        const messages = Object.values(error);
        enqueueSnackbar(messages[0], { variant: "error" });
      });
    }

    if (addUserResponse.data && addUserResponse.data.addUser) {
      enqueueSnackbar("user created", { variant: "success" });
      loadUsers();
    }
  }

  function handleEdit(user) {
    setIdState(user.id);
    setEmailState(user.email);
  }

  async function handleDelete(data) {
    if (typeof data === "object") {
      data.map(id => {
        deleteUser({ variables: { id } });
        if (deleteUserResponse.data && deleteUserResponse.data.deleteUser) {
          enqueueSnackbar("User deleted", { variant: "success" });
        }
      });
    } else {
      deleteUser({ variables: { id: data } });
      if (deleteUserResponse.data && deleteUserResponse.data.deleteUser) {
        enqueueSnackbar("User deleted", { variant: "success" });
      }
    }
  }

  function resetForm() {
    setIdState(null);
    setEmailState("");
  }
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Grid container spacing={8}>
        <Grid item xs={3} className={classes.grid}>
          <Paper className={classes.form}>
            <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
              {idState ? `Edit user: ${emailState}` : "Create user"}
            </Typography>
            <form className={classes.container} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value={idState} />
              <TextField
                className={classes.textField}
                label="E-mail address"
                type="email"
                variant="outlined"
                margin="normal"
                autoComplete="email"
                id="email"
                name="email"
                required={!idState}
                fullWidth
                onChange={e => setEmailState(e.target.value)}
                value={emailState}
                aria-describedby="email-error"
              />
              <FormHelperText id="email-error">
                {errorsState.email}
              </FormHelperText>
              <TextField
                className={classes.textField}
                label="Password"
                variant="outlined"
                margin="normal"
                autoComplete="password"
                id="password"
                name="password"
                required={!idState}
                type="password"
                fullWidth
                onChange={e => setPasswordState(e.target.value)}
                value={passwordState}
                aria-describedby="password-error"
              />
              <FormHelperText id="password-error">
                {errorsState.password}
              </FormHelperText>

              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                className={classes.submit}
                size="large"
                type="submit"
              >
                <AddUserIcon className={classes.icon} /> Save
              </Button>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
                className={classes.submit}
                type="button"
                onClick={resetForm}
              >
                <AddUserIcon className={classes.icon} /> Add new
              </Button>
            </form>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={8} className={classes.grid}>
          <Paper className={classes.root}>
            <Table
              data={usersState}
              className={classes.table}
              columns={{
                id: "ID",
                email: "E-mail address"
              }}
              classes={classes}
              title="Users"
              handleEdit={handleEdit}
              handleDelete={handleDelete}
              filter={true}
              loading={loadingState}
            />
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Users.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Users);
```

In case you need more code, or editing:

### Frontend sandbox: [App](https://jp581.csb.app/) / [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-leftpad-jp581)

### Backend sandbox: [App](https://q9n89.sse.codesandbox.io/) / [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/apollo-server-q9n89)

Any comments, suggestions or whatever will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Button actions trigger on second click

It's because you call

```
if (addUserResponse.called && addUserResponse.loading) {
  enqueueSnackbar("Creating user");
}
```

right after you call `addUser`. The state didn't change when you check `if (addUserResponse.called && addUserResponse.loading)`, the state is the same state before calling `addUser`.

When you click on the second time, you have the state after the first click and this if

```
if (addUserResponse.data && addUserResponse.data.addUser) {
  enqueueSnackbar("user created", { variant: "success" });
  loadUsers();
}
```

is true.

**Solution:**

Create a `useEffect` to handle `addUser` state and remove the if clauses from `handleSubmit`

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (!addUserResponse.called) {
      return;
    }

    if (addUserResponse.loading) {
      enqueueSnackbar("Creating user");
      return;
    }

    if (addUserResponse.error) {
      addUserResponse.error.graphQLErrors.map(exception => {
        const error = exception.extensions.exception;
        const messages = Object.values(error);
        enqueueSnackbar(messages[0], { variant: "error" });
      });
      return;
    }

    enqueueSnackbar("user created", { variant: "success" });
  }, [addUserResponse.called, addUserResponse.loading]);

 function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (idState) {
    } else {
      addUser({
        variables: {
          email: emailState,
          password: passwordState
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

> 2. Data won't refresh after created / deleted.

You should [update your cache after mutation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#updating-the-cache-after-a-mutation) because Apollo doesn't know if you're adding or deleting when you call a mutation.

**Solution:**

```
 const [addUser, addUserResponse] = useMutation(ADD_USER, {
    update: (cache, { data: { addUser } }) => {
      // get current data cache
      const cachedUsers = cache.readQuery({ query: LIST_USERS });

      // create new users
      const newUsers = [addUser, ...cachedUsers.getUsers];

      // save newUsers on cache
      cache.writeQuery({
        query: LIST_USERS,
        data: {
          getUsers: newUsers
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

The same is true for delete user, expect `newUsers` will have current users filtered:

```
const [deleteUser, deleteUserResponse] = useMutation(DELETE_USER, {
    update: (cache, { data: { deleteUser } }) => {
      const cachedUsers = cache.readQuery({ query: LIST_USERS });

      // NOTE: this didn't work because deleteUser return true instead user.
      // I'd suggest change your backend and deleteUser return user id to
      // be able to perform this filter.
      const newUsers = cachedUsers.getUsers.filter(
        ({ id }) => id !== deleteUser.id
      );

      cache.writeQuery({
        query: LIST_USERS,
        data: {
          getUsers: newUsers
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

---

**Note 1:**

You don't need to call `loadUsers` more than one time. Because you update the cache when you perform a mutation, your data will always be the most recent. Because of that I'd call `loadUsers` this way:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    loadUsers();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (usersResponse.called && usersResponse.loading) {
      setLoadingState(true);
    } else if (usersResponse.called && !usersResponse.loading) {
      setLoadingState(false);
    }
  }, [usersResponse.called, usersResponse.loading]);
```

**Note 2**

You don't need to create a state for users, you already have one from `usersResponse.data.getUsers`, but it's your preference. In my case, I removed `const [usersState, setUsersState] = useState([]);` and added

```
const users =
    usersResponse.data && usersResponse.data.getUsers
      ? usersResponse.data.getUsers
      : [];
```

to pass to the table.

---

#### **Edit October 10, 2019**

The main change I did was creating a mutation called `batchDeleteUsers` that delete multiple users in a single call.

**Updating server**

I've made some changes to the server to get the app working. First, `deleteUser` returns `User` and I've created a mutation called `batchDeleteUsers`.

My current mutation schema:

```
type Mutation {
  addUser(email: String!, password: String!): User
  deleteUser(id: String!): User
  batchDeleteUsers(ids: [String!]!): [User]
}
```

My current resolvers:

```
deleteUser: (root, { id }, context) => {
  const user = USERSDB.find(user => user.id === id);
  USERSDB = USERSDB.filter(user => user.id !== id);
  return user;
},
  batchDeleteUsers: (root, { ids }, context) => {
  const users = USERSDB.filter(user => ids.includes(user.id));
  USERSDB = USERSDB.filter(user => !ids.includes(user.id));
  return users;
}
```

**Updating App 1**

Instead using `useLazyQuery` and calling it inside a `useEffect`, I'm using `useQuery`. This way we don't need to perform query inside `useEffect`, it's triggered when component initializes.

```
const usersResponse = useQuery(LIST_USERS);
```

**Updating App 2**

Below is how I create `deleteUser` and `batchDeleteUsers` mutations.

```
const [deleteUser, deleteUserResponse] = useMutation(DELETE_USER, {
  update: (cache, { data: { deleteUser } }) => {
    const cachedUsers = cache.readQuery({ query: LIST_USERS });

    const newUsers = cachedUsers.getUsers.filter(
      ({ id }) => id !== deleteUser.id
    );

    cache.writeQuery({
      query: LIST_USERS,
      data: {
        getUsers: newUsers
      }
    });
  }
});
const [batchDeleteUsers, batchDeleteUsersResponse] = useMutation(
  BATCH_DELETE_USERS,
  {
    update: (cache, { data: { batchDeleteUsers } }) => {
      const cachedUsers = cache.readQuery({ query: LIST_USERS });

      const newUsers = cachedUsers.getUsers.filter(({ id }) => {
        return !batchDeleteUsers.map(({ id }) => id).includes(id);
      });

      cache.writeQuery({
        query: LIST_USERS,
        data: {
          getUsers: newUsers
        }
      });
    }
  }
);
```

**Updating App 3**

This is how I handle the delete users' mutations lifecycle.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!deleteUserResponse.called) {
    return;
  }

  if (deleteUserResponse.loading) {
    enqueueSnackbar("Deleting user");
    return;
  }

  if (deleteUserResponse.error) {
    deleteUserResponse.error.graphQLErrors.map(exception => {
      const error = exception.extensions.exception;
      const messages = Object.values(error);
      enqueueSnackbar(messages[0], { variant: "error" });
    });
    return;
  }

  enqueueSnackbar("user deleted", { variant: "success" });
}, [deleteUserResponse.called, deleteUserResponse.loading]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!batchDeleteUsersResponse.called) {
    return;
  }

  if (batchDeleteUsersResponse.loading) {
    enqueueSnackbar("Deleting users");
    return;
  }

  if (batchDeleteUsersResponse.error) {
    batchDeleteUsersResponse.error.graphQLErrors.map(exception => {
      const error = exception.extensions.exception;
      const messages = Object.values(error);
      enqueueSnackbar(messages[0], { variant: "error" });
    });
    return;
  }

  enqueueSnackbar("users deleted", { variant: "success" });
}, [batchDeleteUsersResponse.called, batchDeleteUsersResponse.loading]);
```

**Updating App 4**

Finally, this is how I handle delete users.

```
function handleDelete(data) {
  if (typeof data === "object") {
    batchDeleteUsers({ variables: { ids: data } });
  } else {
    deleteUser({ variables: { id: data } });
  }
}
```

---

### **My server sandbox: [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/apollo-server-8omw5)**

### **My frontend sandbox: [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-field-gfsbo)**

Comment: The delete is not working but just to comment. It really changes my code. Thank you.

Comment: Great. Might you change the backend to return user id when user is deleted? Then I can update my code to delete user

Comment: Does it have a new URL?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. It is the [same link](https://codesandbox.io/s/apollo-server-q9n89)

Comment: @Maramal I've update the app. I think it's working completely.